# Unwanted repeated execution of code in app.use() in node.js/express.js

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have a problem with unwanted repeated execution of code inside app.use() in my node.js/express.js application:

The following code's output is normal:

**code:**

```
const express = require ('express')
const app = express()

const PORT = 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 
    console.log("Hello World!!!")
    next()
})
```

**Output:**

```
Server started on port 5000
Hello World!!!
```

If I add app.use(express.static('public')) to the end of the code mentioned above, console.log("Hello World!!!") will be executed 17 times instead of one time:

**code:**

```
...

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 
    console.log("Hello World!!!")
    next()
}) 

app.use(express.static('public')) //added line of code
```

**Output**

```
Server started on port 5000
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
```

I would appreciate it if someone could recommend a solution to avoid this repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Try to serve your public assets in a different path.

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory from the /static path prefix.

Comment: I tried this suggested solution. It does not resolve the problem of unwanted repeated execution of the code. Additionally, instead of www.mydomain.com the web visitor should type www.mydomain.com/static which is not practical. I think some extra code should be written in NGINX config files to resolve the path to index.html file. Nevertheless, the main problem is still unresolved.

Comment: try to rearrange the order.
`app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 
    console.log("Hello World!!!")
    next()
})`

Comment: Yes, this one works. Why is this repetition happening, and why can this rearrangement solve the problem?